Translation of cricket, grasshopper and locust in French
I am a native French and English speaker, but I've always been confused by crickets and their translation in both English and French.
How I understand it, and according to Wikipedia, the English word "cricket" is used as an umbrella word for different species of insects, which include "true" crickets, as well as other insects which people consider crickets anyway. Grasshoppers are associated with larger insects than crickets, and are often green or brown. They include locusts.
Now, in French, "grillon" seems to only be associated with the Gryllidae insect family, which are known as the "true" crickets. However, it seems some people also generally refer to grasshoppers as "grillons", which just confuses me. "Sauterelle" is also used for grasshoppers (excluding locusts). "Criquet", if I understand correctly, is then often used to describe smaller crickets that make the characteristic noise at night.
Can anybody help me figure this out? If I wanted to translate the insect "cricket" to French, which word should I use, and in which context? According to this website, there is a common misunderstanding:

La plupart du temps, ce que tu appelles un criquet est en réalité un grillon et tu confonds le criquet avec la sauterelle.


It seems that French does not even have a name for katydids, calling them sauterelles, while the insects that English calls grasshoppers are called criquets or caelifières in French.

And to make things even more confusing, katydid seems to be only an American word — they apparently call them bush crickets in England.

Totally fair, I wasn't sure if this was the right exchange for this question, thanks for the clarification. For now, I've reworded the question to make it more valid for this site, but feel free to edit/close if not.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not clear if it is about scientific taxonomy (which might fit better e. g. on Biology.SE) or about the vernacular names of species in French.

The point is that words appear in context. Otherwise, any good dictionary will do the trick.

Where animals and plants are concerned it is often safer to go by their Latin name (Binomial nomenclature).
■ The page Cricket on Wikipedia tells us that the generic name (i.e.the first word of the nomenclature) of the cricket is Gryllus.
On this same page they mention the Gryllus bimaculatus which can be found in Provence, in the South of France, as we can verify on the site of the Muséum d'histoire naturelle de Paris :

Grillon provençal (Gryllus bimaculatus)
The Muséum d'histoire naturelle being a reliable site I would translate cricket by grillon.
■ On this same site I can see a description of the grande sauterelle verte, which is common in France and it goes by the Latin name of Tettigonia viridissima.

Grande Sauterelle Verte (Tettigonia viridissima)
The Tettigonia viridissima goes by the vernacular name of great green bush-cricket in English.
■ The Latin name of the criquet is Caelifera and switching to wikipedia in English I can find what the vernacular name is in English (grasshopper).
I can read this on this other site about wildlife in France :

Insects in the family Tettigoniidae, (Tettigoniids), are commonly called Bush crickets in English in the UK and Sauterelles in France. In the USA and some other countries that use the English language they are called Katydids.  (Esperanás in Portugal, Grillos in Spain, and Laubheuschrecken in Germany).
If using a dictionary or auto translate the French word Sauterelle will usually translate as Grasshopper BUT this is not correct. The correct French word for Grasshopper is Criquet and Sauterelle is Bush cricket.

It is not a scientific site but what it says is in line with what I have read so far.
■ Locusts are locustes. The word locustes is rarely used in French, they are more usually called criquets migrateurs.
■ Pour sourire : « La bug-enquête » : C’est un grillon, un criquet, une sauterelle ou une locuste?

Yes, in science, but not in literature where the word appears frequently.

Fun fact: locust and langouste cognate.

@jlliagre yeah, learnt that reading the locuste article in Wikipedia. But didn't think it was worth mentioning in an answer here. The question seems to be about insects only. The question says " [crickets]  include locusts" but I think that's wrong, as far as I know, locusts include crickets among other things. Je ne crois pas que les sauterelles soient des locustes. En français on parle de sauterelles pour la  8e plaie d'Égypte,  where in English they use the word locusts (at least in my KJ edition, there might be variations)

Oui, je parlais seulement d'étymologie. Je me sers de la proximité des deux mots pour me souvenir de la signification de locust. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=65378485#65378485

@None "locusts" as in the destructive, swarming insect is more often than not translated as "sauterelles" in French (in "nuée de sauterelles"). See https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nu%C3%A9e+de+sauterelles%2C+nu%C3%A9e+de+locustes&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=fr&smoothing=3

@TeleportingGoat Oui, erreur très répandue (cf la bible) mais pour un entomologiste les sauterelles ne sont pas des locustes, les criquets en sont et la question porte clairement sur un éclaircissement sur la dénomination. Le Dictionnaire historique en langue française (je viens de vérifier) signale bien que l'emploi de sauterelle pour le criquet pèlerin est erroné. Les sauterelles ne volent pas en nuées et elles sont omnivores, ce sont les criquets pèlerins qui détruisent les récoltes.

@TeleportingGoat Wikipedia : "D'un point de vue entomologique, les sauterelles et les criquets sont deux groupes biologiques distincts. Ce sont bien les criquets — et non les sauterelles — qui peuvent être nuisibles pour l'homme, car ils détruisent ses cultures  : quand ils se déplacent par milliers (forme grégaire que n'ont pas les sauterelles), ils peuvent ravager des récoltes entières."
Dans le langage courant, le terme de « sauterelle » parfois employé pour désigner les criquets adultes crée la confusion."

The French and English names for these insects undoubtedly add to this confusion. It seems obvious (but it's wrong) that crickets and criquets should be the same thing. And since hop means sauter, it also seems obvious (but it's wrong) that a grasshopper should be une sauterelle.

@PeterShor It's actually very, very common to have this kind of confusing non-equivalence for common animal names across languages. Penguins aren't pingouins, whales aren't exactly baleines, ravens aren't exactly corbeaux and crows aren't exactly corneilles...

@None Bien sûr, il y a une grande différence entre la nomenclature des entomologistes et le langage courant. Souvent on utilise des termes erronés ou imprécis. À la question "If I wanted to translate the insect "cricket" to French, which word should I use?", la réponse dépend d'à qui on s'adresse.

@TeleportingGoat La presse sérieuse aussi "Des dix plaies d’Egypte, la huitième, à savoir les « sauterelles », comme les traducteurs de la Bible en français l’ont quelque peu improprement nommée, est sans doute celle que la réalité reproduit le mieux. Régulièrement, des portions entières du continent africain se voient privées de récoltes par des nuées de criquets pèlerins ou de criquets migrateurs, les deux espèces de locustes les plus redoutables." (Le Monde)
